# Hide the pointstyle displayed at bottom of chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine-0.7.0.jar in my project..

By default it displays pointstyle("Diamond","X","Point","Square",etc) at the bottom-left corner of chart (which shows which point style is used)

But I don't want to show this in my chart..
Is there any method For hiding this???

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `renderer.setShowLegend(false)` in your code. It will hide the points at the bottom.